# How to read table field's default value?

Tags: database, syntax, progress-4gl, openedge

I want to read a table field's default value. I'm currently using the following syntax:

```
DEF VAR iDefaultValue AS INT NO-UNDO.

iDefaultValue = BUFFER MyTable:BUFFER-FIELD("MyField"):DEFAULT-VALUE.
```

However, when this field gets renamed or there is a typo, it will go thru the compiling process successfully and the possible error is thrown later at the runtime.

Is there any other way to read this value without writting and passing it as string? I'd like to catch any typos or errors with simple syntax check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the fields number in the buffer. This might break if new fields are added or fields are reordered.

```
iDefaultValue = BUFFER u-ort:BUFFER-FIELD(1):DEFAULT-VALUE.
```

Regardless of how you do it you can check for this error during runtime and perhaps log it or whatever fits your application.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iDefaultValue   AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iErrors         AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

iDefaultValue = BUFFER myTable:BUFFER-FIELD("MyField"):DEFAULT-VALUE NO-ERROR.
IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:

    DO iErrors = 1 TO ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES:

        /* 7351 
        BUFFER-FIELD <field-name> was not found in buffer <buffer-name>. (7351)
        You gave a character expression as the argument to the BUFFER-FIELD method of a buffer object, but the character string did not identify any field in that buffer.  Check your PROGRESS dictionary for the field names for the table, and do not abbreviate the field name.
        */

        IF ERROR-STATUS:GET-NUMBER(iErrors) = 7351 THEN DO:
            MESSAGE "Buffer field name was wrong" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        END.

    END.
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just define the variable `like` the field and use its value.

```
DEF VAR iDefaultValue like myTable.MyField NO-UNDO.
/* Don't change the variable! */
```

Of course if the initial value of the database field is changed you need to recompile, otherwise you will get the old initial value.
If you want to make sure to always get the current value and catch errors at compile time you can write

```
DEF VAR iDefaultValue like myTable.MyField NO-UNDO.
iDefaultValue = BUFFER MyTable:BUFFER-FIELD("MyField"):DEFAULT-VALUE.
```

In this case when the fields gets renamed but the code isn't recompiled you will still get a runtime error.
With the following code you should get an error when starting the program in the latter case.

```
DEF VAR iDefaultValue like myTable.MyField NO-UNDO.
define frame f_dummy
  myTable.MyField view-as fill-in skip
with side-labels width 255 stream-io.
iDefaultValue = BUFFER MyTable:BUFFER-FIELD("MyField"):DEFAULT-VALUE.
```

I suppose you will have to decide which behaviour is preferable for you.
All examples assume that the table and field names are known at compile time.